# Long PHP script is restarting unexpectedly

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP script that I call using the $.ajax() Javascript command:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myscript.php",
    data: $("#my-form").serialize()
});
```

### myscript.php (summarized)

```
class myclass{
    public function __construct(){
        $i = 0;
        while($i < $_POST['some_user_defined_var']){
            //$_POST['some_user_defined_var'] = 100
            $this->do_something();
        }
    }
    private function do_something(){
        //this function takes about 1 hour to run
    }
}
new myclass;
```

myscript.php takes about 4 days to run. I notice that roughly 20-28 hours in, the script will unexpectedly restart from the beginning. The $i variable is reset to 0, and the script will startover. Is there a php.ini or other setting that is causing my script to restart?

Comment: Four _days_?! And you're triggering this with an HTTP request? I think you need to seriously rethink your approach. That said, there's really no useful info we can offer you without more code/information.

Comment: Any luck with this? Have you seen my answer?

Comment: I have, thanks. Basically, I changed the structure of the code. I am now running the PHP script with the exec() command so that the HTTP request itself is instant. This seems to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Evan Interesting. I assume you used the code sample provided by http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#86329? If that is working for you then great but be careful because that does mean that you can launch two instances side-by-side. I don't know what `do_something()` does but if data integrity is important then you may wish to figure out a way to only allow this 4-day script to run one at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all of your timeouts and execution times are high enough and [`ignore_user_abort`](http://ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) is `true` then your issue is that `$i` is not being incremented. See below:

```
class myclass{
    public function __construct(){
        $i = 0;
        while($i < $_POST['some_user_defined_var']){
            //$_POST['some_user_defined_var'] = 100
            $this->do_something();

            ++$i; // <-- increment your counter.
        }
    }
    private function do_something(){
        //this function takes about 1 hour to run
    }
}
new myclass;
```

---

Overall, something like this would definitely be better suited as a CRON job/scheduled task. If you need this to be user-activated then I suggest using a combination of CRON and database storage so that a user action can create a DB entry and the CRON job can just look for the entry and act upon it.

A 96 hour HTTP request is absolutely absurd.